# Work done to pump water out of a conical tank into a window above it

Tags: calculus, integration

Water is pumped from a conical tank of top radius 3 ft and a height of 5 ft to a window 10 ft above the tank. The tank is completely full of water. How much work is done?

---

This is what I have so far: $$\int_0^{15}\pi(\text{radius of slice})^2 \cdot (62.4) (15-h)\,dh$$ 
I am having a problem figuring out the radius of the slice

Comment: Hint: chop the conical tank into infinitesimal cylinders.

Comment: This is what i have so far: integral [0, 15] pi(radius of slice)^2 * (62.4) (15-h) I am having a problem figuring out the radius of the slice.

Comment: You might tell us poor Europeans where that $62.4$ comes from. (Also you might set the upper limit of integration to $5$ instead of $15$.)

Comment: @TonyK The density of water at atmospheric pressure and $\approx 50^\circ \text{F}$ is $62.4 \frac{\text{lbm}}{\text{ft}^3}$.

Comment: Thanks for pounds mass, instead of the vague pounds, which could be pounds-force or pounds-mass.

Answer (score 0):

To draw the problem in a coordinate system, choose a positive $x$ axis in the downward direction since the motion is vertical. Take the window at $x = 0$, the top of the tank at $x = 10$ and the bottom of the tank at $x = 15$. The partition of water is therefore the closed interval $[10,15]$ on the $x$ axis.

Take the radius of the cone at $x_i$, the function is $9-3x_i/5$. Then take an element of volume as a circular disk having thickness $\Delta_i x$ and the radius of the cone at $x_i$, the volume is $\Delta_i V = \pi (9-3x_i/5)^2 \Delta_i x$. Then take $62.4$ as the weight of water in pounds per cubic foot, the force required to pump an element is $\Delta_i F = 62.4 \pi (9-3x_i/5)^2 \Delta_i x$.

If $\Delta_i x$ is close to $0$, then the distance through which an element moves is approximately $x_i$. Thus the work done pumping an element to the window is $\Delta_i W = 62.4 \pi x_i (9-3x_i/5)^2 \Delta_i x$ and the integral is:

$$
W = 62.4 \pi \int_{10}^{15} \! x(9-3x/5)^2 \, \textrm{d}x
$$

Answer (score 0):

We'll assume no frictional losses, since we aren't given any information about the flow.

Let the density of water be $\rho = 62.4 \frac{\text{lbm}}{\text{ft}^3}$, the base radius of the cone be $R = 3 \text{ ft}$, the height of the cone be $h = 5 \text{ ft}$, and the vertical distance from the top of the cone to the final water elevation be $d = 10 \text{ ft}$. Of course, the gravitational acceleration is $g = 1 \frac{\text{lbf}}{\text{lbm}}$.

Consider an infinitessimally thin layer of water in the tank at height $y$ above the ground, with a height $d y$. By similar triangles, the radius of this layer of water is $\frac{y}{h} R$. Therefore, the mass of this layer is $d m = \rho d V = \pi \rho \frac{y^2}{h^2} R^2 d y$. The change in gravitational potential energy in bringing this layer to the final elevation is $d U = g (h + d - y) d m$. Therefore, the total energy required is

$$\Delta U = \int_{y = 0}^{y = h} d U = \pi \rho g \frac{R^2}{h^2} \int_0^h y^2 (h + d - y) d y$$

$$= \pi \rho g \frac{R^2}{h^2} \left[ \frac{1}{3} (h + d) y^3 - \frac{1}{4} y^4 \right]_0^h$$

$$= \frac{1}{3} \pi \rho g R^2 h d \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{4} \frac{h}{d} \right]$$

Notice that if we let $V = \frac{1}{3} \pi R^2 h$ be the volume of the cone, then the mass of the water is $m = \rho V = \frac{1}{3} \pi \rho R^2 h$, meaning

$$\Delta U = m g d \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{4} \frac{h}{d} \right]$$

This result is actually quite intuitive, since you are bringing the entire water mass to the same final height, and the center of mass of a cone is located $\frac{1}{4}$ of the height from its base.

I'll leave it to you to substitute the numerical values.